# error- require(PPAutoloader.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to pay money to users when they click on a button. So i have two options adaptive payments and masspay. However, when i used both's SDK based on php, it will give us an error equire(PPAutoloader.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream paypal. I know this was due to missing vendor folder. However, i have searched about this, still no solution. Please help me.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: I have searched about vendor folder and PPAutoloader.php file. But nothing findout. If you have any other solution to solve my actual problem that was to pay users when they click button, please suggest